# Which technology was introduced through "Star Trek" (2009)?

Tags: star-trek, technology, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot, prediction

*Star Trek* has a long history of introducing new technology.

*TOS* & *TNG* introduced us with new technologies, who got adopted like the communicator as mobile phone. When watching *Star Trek* (2009) I noticed the computers and consoles have been changed drastically.

However, I didn't notice anything special or new. Of course there was this fancy transparent screen, but we know them at least since *Stargate* and they are semi reality (Microsoft Surface exists, transparent screens exist).

Which technologies and devices were introduced into the *Star Trek* universe through this movie?  Is there any new tech prediction?

**Clarification**:
I am looking for those unexplained gadgets used by the redskirts.
Explanations for what they could be would be interesting too.
Since I found at one example (which I don't know the real purpose of) I think there has to be more.
Thoughts on their purpose give extra points :)

Comment: Not really, this movie was made to be a fun action romp, not to explore rational science.

Comment: I know, and I didn't like that. But since we're here to dicuss and explore sci-fi I'm curious about the details I didn't see.

Comment: Well, it's kind of iffy whether communicators really introduced the idea. There were radio phones in the 1920s, and car phones in the 40s. Martin Cooper, who helped develop some of the modern cellular technologies was inspired by Star Trek (TOS), but he was also drawing on this earlier technology.

Comment: "I am looking for those unexplained gadgets used by the redskirts." Red "shirts".

Answer (score 15):

I noticed the hover bike in the scene where the police chases young Kirk. While the concept of hover bike itself is not new, I believe it is new to the *Star Trek* universe.

Comment: all those hover things are far too common. I can remember some TNG episodes featuring wheeled cars. Hover cars and bikes didn't exist I think. +1

Comment: The movies used hovering carts (for cargo and equipment), The Motion Picture in particular.

Comment: Harry Kim makes reference to a hover car (or more specifically asks if a truck is an early form of hover car) in The 37's.  I presume they were something that came and went pre-TNG/DS9/VOY times.

Answer (score 14):

None, the movie was built in an almost Fantasy setting compared to how technical *Star Trek* can be in some episodes.

Comment: A good one. Did anyone else notice that Romulans looked a little Orcish? :)

Comment: Although, to be completely honest, in the original Star Trek, Vulcans are quite Elfish.

Comment: You are obviously a speaker of truths

Comment: there you go questioning yourself if Star Trek is really sci-fi and not fantasy :D

Answer (score 7):

I believe the capability of being able to transport onto a ship moving at high warp was a new technology, or at the very least before its time.